# How do you translate "posted on","by" and "continue reading" on Wordpress blog posts to another language?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a basic WordPress theme based on underscores by automatic. The theme's default language is in Norwegian, but I still have "posted on", "by" & "continue reading" under posts displaying in English. What's the proper way to translate this?

I have looked through functions.php and can't see anything in this regard.

TIA, Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't do the translation in a proper way. What you did is called string replacement, not the translation. The proper way of translation is to make a `language_code.po` and `language_code.mo` file using software like **PoEdit** :)

I've added some links below for your convenience.

[WordPress Localization](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/localization/)

[Multilingual WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Multilingual_WordPress)

[WordPress i18n](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers)

[PoEdit](https://poedit.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Found it :)

You edit this on  template-tags.php which is required on functions.php

Comment: how did you find it? What lead you to it? `:-)`

Comment: At first I had just searched "posted by" on functions.php but then I saw the require files at the bottom ( of functions.php ) and thought to check in those as well. They are located under /inc :)

Comment: You didn't do the translation in a proper way. What you did is called string replacement, not the translation. The proper way of translation is to make a language_code.po and language_code.mo file using software like poedit :)

Comment: @obiPlabon Thanks, I googled your answer and there is so much resource on that, like this for example: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/127917/generating-po-mo-translating-files-from-scratch-in-a-wordpress-theme. I'll read on it and try to implement it :)

Comment: Great to hear that (Y)

Comment: @obiPlabon please post your suggestion as an answer so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: Added as an answer :) Thanks